# Facebook share change link text

Tags: facebook

When adding a share button to my site as follows:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.domain.de/christmas-gewinnspiel
```

When I click the button, it takes me to facebook and the the post to wall page, but the link text says "www.domain.de" although the URL of that link is correct ie. (http://www.domain.de/christmas-gewinnspiel), how can I change the the link text?

Answer (score 0):

The page url is giving a 404 response. I think showing the basic domain is the standard behaviour for sharing, the link itself (if you'd click on it) is the correct one, but giving a 404 as described.

Also, think about adding the OpenGraph meta tags to make the shared info look nicer:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/website/